# Get property value from string using reflection in C# - problem with inherited class

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class *Cinherited* which inherits from class *Cbase*.

When I attempt to list the properties for class *Cinherited*, using reflection, it only returns the properties for the base class, *Cbase*.

Here is the (somewhat simplified) code that demonstrates the problem:

```
public class Cinherited: Cbase
{
    public int x;

    public void printProperties()
    {
        Type t = this.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] pi = t.GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in pi)
        {
            // ERROR: Next line only prints properties in base class Cbase.
            Console.Write("Prop: {0}: {1}\n", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(this,null));             
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe its because you haven't got properties in the Cinherited class?

Comment: There is about 20 public propreties in the inherited class. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: public int x; //
it is not a property

Comment: This code works for me, though as Sergey points out, `public int x` declares a *field*.

Comment: Ah, thats it. I need to add {get; set;} after it. Is there any way to access this property via reflection, without using {get; set; }? I need to initialize this value to -1 and don't want the extra typing.

Comment: Ah - so it should be .GetFields() rather than .GetProperties().

Comment: You can do this to init a default value http://pastebin.com/zjHUa03P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've declared *fields* rather than properties on your derived class. You can use code like this to access them:

```
public void PrintField()
{
    Type t = this.GetType();
    FieldInfo[] fi = t.GetFields();
    foreach (FieldInfo field in fi)
    {
        Console.Write("Field: {0}: {1}\n", field.Name, prop.GetValue(this));
    }
}
```

You can set the value of this field by calling `SetValue()`:

```
field.SetValue(this, -1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Properties should be defined as

```
public int x {get; set;}
```

But this is a public field:

```
public int x;
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I ended up using fields instead of properties (fields can be initialized on the same line as they are defined on so it creates cleaner code), so @dlev was closer to the actual answer I was looking for. Thank you again for answering within a minute of me posting this - amazing!!